# jQuery slide up and down on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a facility that slides out a panel both both up and down, it uses `.mousedown`, `.mouseup` and `draggable` and I'm having a couple of problems.

1. the draggable won't go upwards in it's container but the pointer registers the drop (probably related to the movement it makes when everything slides out.
2. the slide-out panels should be over surrounding content. position:absolute works, but trailing words collapse to fill the space it should occupy. I'd like it to stay inline.

[edit] and `hoverClass` doesn't activate either.

http://jsfiddle.net/monsto/tDt2M/ (the outlined word is the menu word)

and code...

```
$(function() {
$('#word').mousedown(function(ev, ui) {
    $("#save").slideDown(100);
    $("#del").slideDown(100);
});    
$('#word').mouseup(function(ev, ui) {
    $("#save").slideUp(100);
    $("#del").slideUp(100);
});    
$('#word').draggable({
    containment: 'parent'
    ,revert: true, revertDuration: 100
});
$('#del').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    ,hoverClass: 'over'
    ,drop: function() {
        var vote = alert("Delete action goes here");
    }
});
$('#save').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    ,hoverClass: 'over'
    ,drop: function() {
        var vote = alert("SAVE");
    }
});
});​
```

Comment: jsFiddle is great for demos but the code should also be posted in the question.  Otherwise, this will not be very helpful to others someday when the link goes bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the hover css class, dynamically set the css as part of the droppable function instead of using the css class...

```
$('.del').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer'
    ,hoverClass: 'over'
    ,over: function() {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#fff');
    }
    ,drop: function() {
        var vote = alert("Delete action goes here");
    }
});
```

For the events, I get pretty good results with this.  The difference if you have to click the word first to see the options (or you could move it to mouse over).  This way, the div has expanded by the time you start dragging...

```
$(function() {
    $('#word').draggable({
        revert: true, revertDuration: 100
    });
    $('#del').droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer'
        ,over: function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#f88');
        }
        ,drop: function() {
            var vote = alert("Delete action goes here");
        }
    });
    $('#save').droppable({
        tolerance: 'pointer'
        ,over: function() {
            $(this).css('background-color', '#8f8');
        }
        ,drop: function() {
            var vote = alert("SAVE");
        }
    });

    $('#word').click(function(e, u){
        $("#save").slideDown(100);
        $("#del").slideDown(100);
    });

    $("#word").bind('dragstop', function(e, u){
        $("#save").slideUp(100);
        $("#del").slideUp(100);
    });
});
```

Comment: Of course, i modded to taste. It seemed that i was close, but your suggestions brought about the the end result: a working li'l popout menu http://jsfiddle.net/monsto/EGVLZ/11/ ...I still have the matter of popping out over the text, but i'll address that separately. Thanks for your help!